# Distance content from border in container with scrollbar

Tags: css, scroll, padding

I have some content in [this containing element](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsx27b6d/) which, as you can see in the JSFiddle, is set to have a fixed height and `overflow: auto;`. When you scroll through the text, you can see that the border touches with the text both above and below.

What I would like to do is to have a "padding" between the border and the text even when scrolling (which the `padding` property unfortunately can't provide), and I wonder if this can be obtained with CSS alone.

If at all possible, **I'd like to avoid having to modify the DOM**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this workaround by adding a balck border at the top and at the bottom around `<main>` which have the same background color of `<div>` like :

```
#content-bar > main {
    border-top: 16px solid black;
    border-bottom: 16px solid black;
}
```

```css
body {
    color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
    font-family: sans-serif;

    background-color: rgb(150, 150, 150);
}

#content-bar {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);

    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;

    min-width: 100%;
    height: 60%;
    left: 0;
}

#content-bar > * {
    padding: 1em;
}

#content-bar > main {
    overflow: auto;
    border-top: 16px solid black;
    border-bottom: 16px solid black;
}

#content-bar > nav {
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;

    min-width: 15%;
}

#content-bar > nav > a {
    text-align: center; /* <---- problem */
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="content-bar">
    <main>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vulputate in arcu id ullamcorper. Pellentesque luctus ut felis vitae tempor. In dui neque, condimentum sit amet diam id, tristique interdum ipsum. In semper nisi leo, at consequat sem interdum feugiat. Proin vestibulum, turpis in tempus pellentesque, enim libero auctor libero, sit amet ultrices est felis sit amet nisl. Mauris vel mi mi. Suspendisse eleifend laoreet mi a congue. Fusce non libero in velit sodales pharetra nec in nisl. Phasellus elementum a odio eu sodales. Nunc luctus, est non pellentesque tristique, nibh mi pulvinar tellus, ut tincidunt dolor eros at leo. Donec varius dolor eget quam aliquet varius. In at iaculis est. Proin at purus sed ligula tincidunt ullamcorper sit amet a elit. Duis mollis lacinia mi, non aliquam arcu pulvinar ac. Aenean quis imperdiet lorem.</p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam vulputate in arcu id ullamcorper. Pellentesque luctus ut felis vitae tempor. In dui neque, condimentum sit amet diam id, tristique interdum ipsum. In semper nisi leo, at consequat sem interdum feugiat. Proin vestibulum, turpis in tempus pellentesque, enim libero auctor libero, sit amet ultrices est felis sit amet nisl. Mauris vel mi mi. Suspendisse eleifend laoreet mi a congue. Fusce non libero in velit sodales pharetra nec in nisl. Phasellus elementum a odio eu sodales. Nunc luctus, est non pellentesque tristique, nibh mi pulvinar tellus, ut tincidunt dolor eros at leo. Donec varius dolor eget quam aliquet varius. In at iaculis est. Proin at purus sed ligula tincidunt ullamcorper sit amet a elit. Duis mollis lacinia mi, non aliquam arcu pulvinar ac. Aenean quis imperdiet lorem.
        </p>
    </main>

    <nav>
      <a href="#">Element 1</a>
      <a href="#">Element 2</a>
      <a href="#">Element 3</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I don't know why that didn't occur to me sooner. Thank you so much.